# How Many frames in 8 minutes for a video?

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes, video, frame-rate

What are the correct final frames in 8 minutes for the video? I want precisely perfect timing. So I won't lose track of time.

Comment: Why is this question considered "opinion-based"? Is it about the "right" setting for the frame rate? Or is it a question of how many frames you get for an 8-minute rendered video? Is the video rendered at all or is it about video footage that is used for VFX? The question is unclear and ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of frames for any time length depends on the **frame rate**.
The frame rate is the number of **frames per second** (FPS).
In Blender, the default frame rate is 24 FPS. You can change the frame rate on the *Output Properties > Frame Rate* setting.

You can do a bit of math and figure out the exact number of frames for any length of time by multiplying the frame rate by the number of seconds.

8 minutes = 480 seconds. 480 seconds times 24 frames per second = 11520 frames.

But if the frame rate is, for exemple, at 30 FPS, then it's gona be 480 x 30, which is 14400.

So before figuring out the total number of frames you have to know what frame rate your project is going to be set to.